# compressed sensing versus Lomb-Scargle

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, compressive-sensing, least-squares

Say I have a signal that's the sum of only a few sine/cosine waves, and some noise, which has been measured at random times. I would like to find the frequencies of the waves. With this goal in-mind, what are the trade-offs between these two methods:

1. Calculate the Lomb-Scargle periodogram, where the positions of the peaks give the frequencies.
2. Use compressed sensing with a basis of sines and cosines to find the sparse solution.

Since the spectrum is sparse, will compressed sensing require fewer measurements to get the power spectrum? Is one method more accurate than the other, or more robust to noise?

Comment: hm, calculating a Lomb-Scargle periodogram (1.) is something I always considered an example of compressed sensing (2.), just that the sensing had been done before and now I'm calculating the best-suited orthogonal basis of sines myself.

Comment: Yes but the math under the hood is pretty different

Comment: hm? Is it? Lomb-Scargle looks for a base of sines that is orthogonal w.r.t. the times you sample. Compressed sensing with a sine base looks for the base of sines that have the least error when projecting on them. Especially in AWGN, that leads to exactly the same orthogonality.